# Accessing Docker from host network using domain name

Tags: docker, networking, server

hey guys I have a docker container A with a domain name attached to it on a host B with a domain name attached to it as well.....how can I access the said container A via A's domain name rather than an B's ip address or domain name from computer C on the host B's local network.

thus `C -> A( via wwww.cname.url)` rather than `C -> B( www.bname.url:port) -> A`

E.G.

the following is a docker-compose with services

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  php:
    links:
      - mysql
    image: arm32v6/php:7.1.24-fpm-alpine3.8-lavalite
    networks:
      - backend
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - ./website/:/var/www/html/
    privileged: true
  node:
    domainname: docker.local
    hostname: node
    networks:
      frontend:
        aliases:
          - node.docker.local
    links:
      - "apache:dev.docker.local"
    depends_on:
      - apache
    image: arm32v7/node:latest
    entrypoint: yarn
    command: twill-dev
    volumes:
      - ./website:/usr/src/app
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "3001:3001"
  apache:
    domainname: docker.local
    hostname: dev
    image: arm32v7/httpd:2.4
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      frontend:
        aliases:
          - apache
          - dev.docker.local
      backend:
        aliases:
          - apache
    privileged: true
    ports:
      - "8880:80"
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - ./website/:/var/www/html/
      - ./httpd.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
      - ./fpm.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
  mysql:
    image: yobasystems/alpine-mariadb:arm32v7
    volumes:
      - ./datadir:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - backend
    environment:
      - MYSQL_VERSION=5.7
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpassword
      - MYSQL_USER=test
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=testpass
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=test_db
networks:
  frontend:
    external:
      name: localnet
  backend:
```

I want to be able to access service **apache** by its domain name set to *dev.docker.local* the ip of which is on a network 17.18.0.1/24

The host has an IP which is on a network 192.168.1.0/24 with a domain name dev.server.local

I have a dev pc on the network 192.168.1.0/24 and it can access the service containers via the hosts IP and usually a port exposed for the particular service.

**UPDATE**
The host can be reached at server.local from outside the network
my network interface has the following entries

```
dns-search server.local
dns-domain server.local
```

the docker container has the following

hostname nginx
domainname server.local

do I need to also edit a host file or resolv.conf file?

It seems the host is running avahi service discovery. Would this affect anything?

So can I

- set an internal domain set to the host and have docker containers on subdomains? How would outside devices access this via the domain?
- attach the docker container to be on the host's network thus having an ip in the 192.168.1.0/24 and being able to be pinged by devices on that network as well. Will the domain resolve to it?
- Is there a dynamic DNS software I can  use that can hook this up to me so that its not a manual process. Thus it will detect the server and route incoming requests to it via the domain name?

Comment: That totally depends on your setup, how have you set up the networks and ports? Are you running a swarm? Please provide more config and context information :)

Comment: @SvenHakvoort no swarm. General concept. I want to spin up docker containers but instead of accessing them through the host's ip and port I want to access them as if they were devices on the host's network so to be visible to other computers on the host's network.

Comment: Can you share the config file or run commands for docker?

Comment: @SvenHakvoort please forgive the ignorance but what config? docker or host? The host is a debian server running docker and i spin up dynamic containers. Do you need the network config? or docker environment config?

Comment: No problem :) i mean the docker compose or docker run command. I.e. how you start and configure your docker containers

Comment: @SvenHakvoort hope this helps

Comment: I think you are trying to use Docker in way that it hasn't been designed for. Containers are not supposed to be accessed by using their IP from outside. Also, docker networks are not real networks but *network namespaces*.

Comment: @tgogos ahhh i see so it is  not possible? Even with the "macvlan" driver?

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible or not, but regardless of that I would definitely not recommend it. I would recommend a setup where all connections on domain b are passed to docker and docker internally uses subdomains (with nginx container for example) to route the request to the correct container

Comment: @SvenHakvoort well if this is an option then so be it but I was wondering if there is a unique way to do it so as to not go through host's ip but atleast through a host subdomain that gets routed to the container's ip? I'm not knowledgable in this field so I'm not sure

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by configuring an nginx container with the containers bound to the subdomain.

So for example the host is accessible by domain `example.com` and you want the php container to be accessible on `php.example.com` you could use a setup like the following:

```
services:
  php:
    image: arm32v6/php:7.1.24-fpm-alpine3.8-lavalite
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=php.example.com
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    depends_on:
      - php
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
```

Any request to the subdomain would first be send to the host, this is bound by nginx, which in turn registers that because the subdomain `php` is requested it should send the user to that container.

I hope this can help you and if you have any questions please let me know

Comment: Will try this again

Comment: IS nginx-proxy required?

Comment: @Kendall, in this case yes. since the VIRTUAL_HOST is a functionality specific to jwilder/nginx-proxy. But you might be able to simulate this with apache however I have no experience with that. I used this for my own API setup and therefore know that this works, so that is why my example uses nginx

Comment: no dice. I tried everything I know how and it did not work. I can't ping the container from outside as well as inside